# ElectronJS communicating with remote website containing websocket

Tags: electron

I'm writing an ElectronJS application.  When it starts up, it will navigate to a **remote** website whose page contains a websocket.  There is a 'start' button on the displayed webpage that when I click it, the websocket transfers data to my ElectronJS app - I can see the message in the 'chrome debugger' panel (console), but how do I pass the message back to the main process so that the message can be processed (the message contains command processing instructions)?

Comment: My first-thought, worst-case scenario would be to create a hidden web page and use that to handle the socket.io communications.  I put this as a comment instead of an answer because I expect you'll be getting better answers soon.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using the webview tag to load the guest content (remote page), if i'm right then you may allow node context in that webview tag by `nodeintegration` attribute. See https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#nodeintegration for more details.

If you are using the `browserWindow` then page already available to use electron-node context.

In both cases you have to extend the code of the remote page to use electron environment. Probably you may apply some hacks on the remote page objects when you have page loaded. But it could be very-very painful